# Create a (phonegap based?) app that listens for incoming HTTP calls

Tags: android, ios, networking, cordova

I am looking for options around creating a multi-platform application that will react to a HTTP call made to it. To explain my situation:

- I have software running on client machines which is capable of making HTTP requests, specifically passing information via GET;
- I can adapt the software to accept a manually inputted IP address and any other information (such as authentication tokens) but not really change the comms method;
- The requirement is that this software can pass small amounts of information, on the fly, to an app running on a smartphone;
- I'm able to specify networking restrictions, such as being on the same local network etc;
- It's not really viable for me to create a server to sit between the app and the client.

My thinking is that I could create a simple app to effectively act as a server, sitting and listening for a HTTP call and acting on the information passed to it.

Phonegap crossed my mind purely for the cross-platform capability; Ultimately, if it needed to be native development, whilst not preferred, it is an option.

Everything I've found on the subject thus far is either specific to a platform, usually with no alternative on competing platforms, or is reliant on the app as a client or an intermediary server handling the connections.

My question is, is such a thing - effectively setting up an iPhone or Android device as a server with a listening port - actually possible in Phonegap, or at all?

I appreciate that there are some (very valid) security concerns with the above approach - additional controls will be put into place to deal with that, right now I'm at the beginning of the search and looking to see which is the most viable way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that your approach is a bad idea. You have to keep in mind that the OS can kill your app if it is in the background any time it feels like it. I would look more into using a push service to send the app any updates. That way, even if the app was killed, when the user opens the app it has the latest info. My 2cents.